# how to extract the number 8 from this php array

Tags: php, arrays, count

the following result is vardump of a return object of sql which is counting my table records

```
Array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(1) "8" } }
```

and number '8' is the number of records , how can i echo this number directly

Comment: `echo $myArray[0]["COUNT(*)"];` or set an alias in your SQL query to give the value a different name

Comment: `$array[0]['COUNT(*)']` should do it, but for the love of all that is holy, use SQL aliases for aggregated columns!

Comment: YES worked, you are a prince Mark Baker , do you recommend a link to read to let me understand why i could not solve it myself.

Comment: EatPeanutButter , thank you for recommendation

Comment: [Column aliases](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) here's a quick tut on aliases, basically they let you assign a more sensible name to your aggregated query. In your example you could change your sql to something like SELECT count(*) AS total .... Then in your php you could access $array[0]['total'] - makes for better readability.